# Multiple Axios requests combine

Tags: node.js, rest, axios, array-map

Sorry for my bad English. But i'm stuggling with an problem and I hope someone can help me out.

```
const FinalResult = [];

const users = [
  {
    short: "gurdt",
    gameTag: "gurdt#3199278"
  },
  {
    short: "lc",
    gameTag: "LC_92#4607792"
  },
  {
    short: "ray",
    gameTag: "The_Green_Ray"
  },
  {
    short: "leon",
    gameTag: "Theaxeman777#7613572"
  }
];

async function getData(user) {
  const config = {
    method: "get",
    url: `https://my.callofduty.com/api/papi-client/stats/cod/v1/title/mw/platform/uno/gamer/${encodeURIComponent(
      user
    )}/profile/type/wz`,
    headers: {
      Cookie:
        "TOKEN-1234"
    }
  };

  const rawResponse = await axios(config);
  const result = {
    user: user,
    ...rawResponse.data.data.weekly.all.properties
  };

  return result;
}

users.map((user) => {
  const data = getData(user.gameTag);

  FinalResult.push(data);
  return false;
});

console.log(FinalResult);
```

What I want is that he loops over the `users` and make here one big array of all the results `FinalResult`.

Hope that you know what I mean, otherwise tomorrow I will update this question as I'm on my computer and put more info..

Comment: You have a syntax error... `users.map((user)) =>` should be `users.map((user) =>`

Comment: You still have syntax errors. You can only use `await` within `async` functions

Comment: Thanks @Phil just changed it and format it a bit.

Comment: Changed it again @Phil bet now the console log keep saying `Promise { <pending> },`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each `users` entry to a promise that resolves with the data you want. Pass this array of promises to [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to create a single promise you can await.

```js
// this will make for cleaner code
const gamerApi = axios.create({
  baseURL:
    "https://my.callofduty.com/api/papi-client/stats/cod/v1/title/mw/platform/uno/gamer/",
  headers: {
    Cookie: "TOKEN-1234;",
  },
});

const promises = users.map(async (user) => {
  const { data } = await gamerApi.get(
    `${encodeURIComponent(user.gameTag)}/profile/type/wz`
  );
  return {
    user,
    ...data.data.weekly.all.properties,
  };
});

// If you're currently in an async function...
const finalResult = await Promise.all(promises);

// otherwise, use .then()...
Promise.all(promises).then((finalResult) => {
  // use finalResult here
});
```

The result will be an array of objects with a `user` property merged with whatever is in the response.

Comment: Thanks @phil this is much cleaner and better to read! But on `const finalResult = await Promise.all(promises)` I get the following warning `Parsing error: Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function`

Comment: @Gurdt that's why I added the extra bit under that

Comment: Sorry about that, but the last part fixxed for me!! You make my day!